# Save the Data Grid Data in Database using WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to save all the data grid data in database. I fill the data grid from the text boxes. How to save all the **data grid** data on one button click in database in WPF C#?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Question is incomplete.! Can you Show your Data-grid and Database Table-Where You want to save data.

Comment: i'm new to wpf but i tried this  foreach (DataGridItem dgi in AddProducts.Items)
            {
                string id = dgi.Cells[0].Text;
                string name = dgi.Cells[1].Text;
    } but that doesn't work because in wpf datagriditem doesn't exists

Comment: i have database table of orderdetail in which i have to save product with price and their quantity and discount. in my wpf application i created these four textboxes when i click on add button these all values inserted in my datagrid not in database. after entering the other detail when i click confirm order then all the data have to be save in database

Comment: @JIYA please use the edit button on the bottom left of your question to add these sort of details and explanations.

Comment: Please add more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `System.Data.DataTable` as your `ItemsSource` for the `DataGrid`, inserting the `Datagrid`'s data into an SQL Database table is relatively easy. Use `SqlBulkCopy`.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn)
                    {
                    DestinationTableName =
                        $"[YourSchemaName].[{YourTableName}]"
                    };
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(((DataView) yourDataGrid.ItemsSource).Table);
}
```

There are some caveats, of course. The `DataTable` and the destination SQL table have to have the same structure (columns, etc.).

If you are not using a `DataTable` as your `DataGrid`'s `ItemSource`, then you will have to find your own solution.